# Django include applications from subfolders

Tags: django, python-2.7

In my django project I collect all applications under an apps folder, when I tried to include it into settings.py and run the server I got module xxx not found.

My project folder's structure is the following:

```
myProject
-media
-myProject
--apps
---registration
----__init__.py
----models.py
----views.py
----urls.py
--settings.py
--urls.py
-static
-templates
-manage.py
```

urls.py under myProjects:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()



    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        # Examples:
        # url(r'^$', 'myProject.views.home', name='home'),

        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
         url(r'^registration/', include(myProject.apps.registration.urls)),
    )
```

urls.py under apps/registration

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
   url(r'^registration/$', 'nonsenseprojects.views.registration', name='registration'),

)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'registration', dosen't work
   # 'apps.registration', dosen't work
    # 'myProject.apps.registration' dosen't work

)
```

Terminal error message:

```
>  thor@thor:~/Documents/myProjects$ sudo python manage.py runserver
> 127.0.0.1:8008   ImportError: No module named registration
```

How can I set the application's path in settings.py

Thank you in advance

Comment: Should it not be `myProject.apps.registration` if the it is in myproject/apps folder ?

Comment: `apps` doesn't have the `__init__.py` file so is not a module and cannot be imported.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app work with sub folder.. Try below

In your `settings.py` all you have to do is

```
myProject.apps.registration
```

urls.py under apps/registration

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myProject.apps.registration.views',
    (r'^$', 'Submit_url'),
)
```

then best way to import like

> from myProject.apps.registration.models import `<ModelName>`